# C# Saving Object Values

Tags: c#, wcf, object, persistence, instance

Hope someone can help me with this. I have a method (user_login) than prompts for a user to login and then generates and returns an invoice and a token.

The problem is that if the user has already logged in (i keep this in a List), the method svr.logonex must not be called. I should retrieve the values from the previous instance. I guess i must save the svr variable but i dont know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
public EPS30Ora.LogonResult User_Login(input_params inputparams)
        {
          EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr();
         if (Users.Exists(Username => Username.Username.Equals(inputparams.Username)))
            {
                List<input_params> selected = Users.Where(Username => Username.Username.Equals(inputparams.Username)).ToList();
                svr.PrepareByMoney(selected[0].ck, 1, inputparams.meter_number, 10, 0, ref cal);
            }
            else 
            {

                Log_Res = svr.LogOnEx("EDEESTE", inputparams.VSID, inputparams.Username, inputparams.Password, "EPS30Ora", ref inputparams.ck);

                if (Log_Res == EPS30Ora.LogonResult.psOK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Users.Add(inputparams);
                        object tr_bl = svr.GetInvoiceData(inputparams.ck, svr.Confirm(inputparams.ck));
                    }
                    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Se ha producido una excepción: " + ex);

                    }
              }


            }

            return Log_Res;
        }
```

Comment: I think you should provide some more background information.

Comment: You could put in a check just before the svr.LogOnEx method to check to see if the user is already logged on (by checking the values in your list).  You could have if then statement, if(Users.IsLoggedOn(inputParams.UserName)) { //do nothing } else { //svr.LogOnEx }. If you want to keep track of the svr variable, you can create a global variable and set it equal to the svr variable on each iteration of the above method.  This way the next iteration of the method, you would be able to reference the global variable for the previous iteration and the local variable for the current iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. i will try the if and the global variable and comment the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to pull this:

EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr();

out of the Login method, and move it into whatever is calling this method in order to keep this object in scope longer. Otherwise the object is destroyed when you return from the method.

You can then pass it as an argument into this method, for example:

```
// Start user process

EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr();

if (Users.Exists(Username => Username.Username.Equals(inputparams.Username))) {
 // do something
}
else {

}
```

...

```
public LogOn(EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr, input_params inputparams)
{
Log_Res = svr.LogOnEx("EDEESTE", inputparams.VSID, inputparams.Username, inputparams.Password, "EPS30Ora", ref inputparams.ck);
}
```

Comment: Excelent, i will try it and get back with the results!

Comment: i will post the full code , maybe it helps to understand better what am i doing wrong.

Comment: i pulled EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr() out of the LogonEx method and worked great. This problem is solved. THANKS A LOT:

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace EPSInvoice_ServiceLibrary
{

    public class EPS_Service : IEPS_Service
    {
        List<input_params> Users = new List<input_params>();
        List<token_data> token_data = new List<token_data>();
        public decimal cal;


        public EPS30Ora.LogonResult Invoice(input_params inputparams)
        {
            EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr();
            EPS30Ora.LogonResult Log_Res = new EPS30Ora.LogonResult();
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            Trace.Indent();

            if (Users.Exists(Username => Username.Username.Equals(inputparams.Username)))
            {
                List<input_params> selected = Users.Where(Username => Username.Username.Equals(inputparams.Username)).ToList();
                Trace.WriteLine("Username: " + inputparams.Username + " ya está logeado " + selected[0].ck);
                //    svr.PrepareByMoney(selected[0].ck, 1, inputparams.meter_number, 10, 0, ref cal);
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {
                    Log_Res = svr.LogOnEx("EDEESTE", inputparams.VSID, inputparams.Username, inputparams.Password, "EPS30Ora", ref inputparams.ck);
                    if (Log_Res == EPS30Ora.LogonResult.psOK)
                    {
                        Users.Add(inputparams);
                        Trace.WriteLine("Login OK. Username: " + inputparams.Username);
                        svr.PrepareByMoney(inputparams.ck, 1, inputparams.meter_number, 10, 0, ref cal);
                        object tr_bl = svr.GetInvoiceData(inputparams.ck, svr.Confirm(inputparams.ck));
                        token_data.Add(new token_data() { transfer_number = (string)((object[])(((object[])(((object[])(((object[])(tr_bl))[4]))[1]))[0]))[0] });
                        Trace.WriteLine("Transacción Finalizada. NTC obtenido: " + inputparams.ck);
                        Trace.Unindent();
                    }
                }

                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Se ha producido una excepción: " + ex);
                }
            }
         return Log_Res;
        }




    }



}
```